# Spring Integration Channel Interceptor SOAP Envelope

Tags: spring-integration

Is there any way to get the entire SOAP message inside channel interceptor call back methods ? Is there any MessageContext injected by default to any of the callback methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question doesn't sound good. The `ChannelInterceptor` does not do anything with SOAP. They know only about the channels and messages to pass.

In general Spring Integration is *stateless*, so no any context injected to the channel interceptor.

Any `MessageContext` is responsibility of your own application.

One of the approach is a `MessageHeaders` as I recommend you in your other questions: before sending message to the channel you store something to its headers and than you have access to that object from the channel interceptor methods via provided `message`.